# delete previous object fields and make new fields in array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, list, object

I have a list of objects in javascript where I have a list with 1 field which is org_name like this:

```
const list=[
{ org_name:"Test1"},
{ org_name:"Test2"}
]
```

Now I want to change this list to:

```
const list=[
{ text:"Test1",value:"Test1"},
{ text:"Test2",value:"Test2"}
]
```

What I am doing is:

```
list.map(el => ({ ...el, text: el.org_name, value: el.org_name }));
```

Its not working,Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: Assign to something (list is a const) and remove the ...el: `const newList = list.map(({org_name})=> ({ text: org_name, value: org_name }));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just drop the `...el` part since you don't need it.

```js
const list=[
  { org_name:"Test1"},
  { org_name:"Test2"}
];

const out = list.map(el => {
  return { text: el.org_name, value: el.org_name };
});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Worth an answer?

Answer (score 1):

`Array.map` creates new array. You want to update existing array, so loop through the array and update the object keys.

```js
const list = [ { org_name: "Test1" }, { org_name: "Test2" } ];
list.forEach(el => {
  el.text = el.org_name;
  el.value = el.org_name;
  delete el.org_name;
});
console.log(list)
```